# Putting an IF statement inside a Loop?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that accepts inputs of even numbers until the user enters a odd number then it stops and adds all the even inputs.

The problem I am having is that I'm intending to use an `if` statement to determine if the number is even or not but once the program has run I need it to run again so the user can keep inputting numbers until they input a odd one.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value;
    cout << "Please enter a possitive number: ";
    cin >> value;
    if (value%2 == 0) { // divides the value entered by 2 too determine whether or not its even.
        cout << "Please enter another even number: ";
    }
    else
    {

    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any loops here, and you don't have any code to add up the numbers. `while (value is even) { add numbers and prompt for another number }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop in order to ask for input again in case the value is even.

You will enter the `while` loop only if `value` is even. And you will loop until `value` input is even.

You then need another `int` which represents the sum and add the value to the sum each time you enter the loop (each time you have an even number)

Note that with this solution you don't need an `if` statement. The condition is in the `while` loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value;
    int sum=0;
    cout << "Please enter a possitive number: "<<endl;
    cin >> value;
    while (cin && value%2 ==0){
        sum+=value;
        cout << "Please enter another even number: "<<endl;;
        cin >> value;
    }

    cout<<"Sum of even number: "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check if the reading is successful, or it may cause infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response would their be a way to count the number of values entered?

Comment: @Aaron yes, there would. Write program to count, compile and run.

Comment: @Aaron Yes. You need to have another `int` that start at 0 and that you keep incrementing each time you enter the loop. This will give you the total number of even number

Comment: If I were to write something like cout << "Average of even numbers: " << counter/sum << endl; and then add a variable for counter and a counter++ in the loop would that work @MikeCAT?

Comment: @Aaron Yes. but it would be `cout << "Average of even numbers: " << sum/counter << endl;`

Comment: @Aaron You may want something like this: `cout << "Average of even numbers: " << (double)sum/counter << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value;
    vector<int> inputs;
    cout << "Please enter a possitive number: ";
    while (cin >> value) { // loop while successfully read an integer
        if (value%2 == 0) { // divides the value entered by 2 to determine whether or not its even.
            inputs.push_back(value);
            cout << "Please enter another even number: ";
        }
        else
        {
            break; // get out of this loop
        }

    }

    // add all the even inputs
    int sum = 0;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = inputs.begin(); it != inputs.end(); it++) {
        sum += *it;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the addition inside the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value;
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a possitive number: ";
    while (cin >> value) { // loop while successfully read an integer
        if (value%2 == 0) { // divides the value entered by 2 to determine whether or not its even.
            sum += value;
            cout << "Please enter another even number: ";
        }
        else
        {
            break; // get out of this loop
        }

    }

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the vector is kind of a waste - You can add up any number to a running total inside the loop as long as it is even. There is absolutely no need to remember the entered values.

Comment: @tofro I agree, but I used it because I interpreted the question as all additions should be done after an odd number is entered.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
int value;
bool run = true;
cout << "Please enter a possitive number: ";
while(run)
{

     cin >> value;
     if (value%2 == 0) { // divides the value entered by 2 too determine whether or not its even.
        cout << "Please enter another even number: ";
    }
    else
    {
       run=false
    }
}
```

It is sudo code modeled similar to your loop, so not the best way, also most likely there might be syntax error, but should give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

one more way to check whether it is even or odd is to check lowest bit:

`#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int enteredValue = 0;
    std::vector<int> result;

    do {
        std::cout<<"Please enter even number : ";
        std::cin>>enteredValue;
        result.push_back(enteredValue);
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }while(!(enteredValue & 0x01)); //check the lowest bit

    std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), [](int x){ std::cout<<x<<' '; });
    return 1;
}`